# Custom caption output for custom image size

Tags: post-thumbnails, images, captions

I've done a lot of searching and have found out how to customize the `img_caption_shortcode` oputput. What I can't seem to figure out how to do:

Add a specific class to the caption's output if a certain custom thumbnail size was chosen in the media uploader.

So, to elaborate a bit:

I created a new image size:

```
add_image_size( 'profile-image', 300, 300 );
```

I added that to the media uploader image size options:

```
/**
 * Add Custom Image sizes to Media Uploader
 */
add_filter( 'image_size_names_choose', 'my_custom_image_sizes' );

function my_custom_image_sizes( $sizes ) {
    return array_merge( $sizes, array(
        'profile-image' => __('Profile Image with Caption'),
    ) );
}
```

I found this code to hook into the `img_caption_shortcode` function:

```
function my_custom_img_caption_shortcode($a, $attr, $content = null) {

    extract(shortcode_atts(array(
        'id'    => '',
        'align' => 'alignnone',
        'width' => '',
        'caption' => ''
    ), $attr));

    if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) )
        return $content;

    if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';

    return '<div ' . $id . 'class="wp-caption ' . esc_attr($align) . '" style="width: ' . (10 + (int) $width) . 'px">'
. do_shortcode( $content ) . '<p class="wp-caption-text">' . $caption . '</p></div>';
}
//Add the filter to override the standard shortcode
add_filter( 'img_caption_shortcode', 'my_custom_img_caption_shortcode', 10, 3 );
```

Now I would like to be able to change the caption output if the `profile-image` thumbnail size is chosen. I thought I would just try to output the thumbnail size (`size-profile-image`) class that WP provides to the caption's div wrapper, but I can't figure out how to do that.

Comment: I can do it with jQuery pretty easily, but that feels like a cop out: `$('img.size-profile-image').closest('div.wp-caption').addClass('profile-image');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need only a regex to catch the class from content, check if the class for you size is one of the assigned class and if so add to output, something like:

```
function my_custom_img_caption_shortcode($a, $attr, $content = null) { 

  extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'id' => '', 'align' => 'alignnone', 'width' => '', 'caption' => ''
  ), $attr) );

  if ( 1 > (int) $width || empty($caption) ) return $content;

  if ( $id ) $id = 'id="' . esc_attr($id) . '" ';

  // set the initial class output
  $class = 'wp-caption';
  // use a preg match to catch the img class attribute
  preg_match('/<img.*class[ \t]*=[ \t]*["\']([^"\']*)["\'][^>]+>/', $content, $matches);
  $class_attr = isset($matches[1]) && $matches[1] ? $matches[1] : false;
  // if the class attribute is not empty get an array of all classes
  if ( $class_attr ) {
    foreach ( explode(' ', $class_attr) as $aclass ) {
      if ( strpos($aclass, 'size-') === 0 ) $class .= ' ' . $aclass;
    }
  }

  $class .= ' ' . esc_attr($align);

  return sprintf (
    '<div %sclass="%s" style="width:%dpx">%s<p class="wp-caption-text">%s</p></div>',
    $id, $class, (10 + (int)$width), do_shortcode($content), $caption
  );

}
```

Comment: Thank you for posting. Unfortunately I could not get that to work.  `var_dump($class_attr);` returns: 'bool(false)`, so maybe a problem with the regex? Regexes make my eyes bleed, so that's as much as I can tell.

Comment: @Gabriel was a regex error (it worked only if the class was the first attribute of img), now I've insert the fixed versions in answer. Try now.

Comment: Killer! It works. I would buy you a beer right now if I could (and if you like beer :). Thanks!

Comment: Now, for bonus beers: it would be really cool if it was less specific and could output whatever `size-*` class the image had on it. No worries if you don't want to try that, though. You've already helped a lot. Cheers.

Comment: I like beer, friend. See the edit ;) @Gabriel

Comment: Very cool. The scope of this changed just a bit: we decided not to add a new image size. So I tweaked your setup to just grab all classes from the image and add them to the caption div. I also added in the image description. I really appreciate your time. It helped me on the project I'm doing, and it else helped me learn. I've made a promise to myself that I won't use anyone else's code in a project unless I take the time to learn how each bit works. Except maybe for regex..I hate that stuff :). I'll post my revised code below.